# Diverging series with positive bounded terms

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Consider the series $\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\frac{a_k}{k}$, such that $0 < a_k < B$, where if $B$ is a strictly positive number. If the series diverges, is the sequence eventually a finite sequence, i.e. is $a_k = a$ $\forall k \geq K$, where $K$ is a finite natural number.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily, $a_k$ could be something like $1+\frac{1}{2^k}$. The sum $\sum \frac{a_k}{k}$ diverges by comparison with $\sum \frac{1}{k}$. There are many other examples.

Comment: Thank you, I suppose $a_k  = b_k + c_k$, where $\sum_{k}\frac{c_k}{k}$ converges but $\liminf_{k}c_k$ is strictly bounded away from 0  should suffice.

Comment: You may have meant $\inf b_k\gt 0$.

Comment: sorry, $\liminf_k b_k > 0$.